# How can we control only the Right and Left arm of the nao robot

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have succesfuly installed the nao package and I am able to publish the nao_sensors info. I want to now publish data to control only the arms of the nao robot and see the simulation of it in choregraphe. Is this possible with nao stack ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11516/how-can-we-control-only-the-right-and-left-arm-of-the-nao-robot./) by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is now a general joint angle / joint trajectory control in the [trunk of the nao stack](http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nao/) (check nao_controller.py in nao_ctrl). It allows to control any joint or chain on the Nao with ROS messages or an actionlib server.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2